# PHP writing to text file

Tags: php, html, file

I am working on a project for my class in college and in this project we have to write usernames and passwords to a text file. However whenever I try to run this, the information does not get written into the document. Any recommendation would be very much appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
$User = $_GET["user"];
$name = $_GET["name"];

$_SESSION["user"] = $User;
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;

$pass = rand(100000, 999999);
$file = fopen("accounts.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, $User);
fwrite($file, $pass);
fwrite($file, $name);

fclose($file);

$array = explode(" ", $name);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$message = "Hello $name, you are registered. Your password is: $pass";
mail($User, "Homework Registration", $message);
print("All Done");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I figured it out. I did not have permissions for writing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the php tag after your  `print` statement like this

```
print("All Done");
?>
```

**Note :**

1. Make sure that you have enough permissions to create and edit to the file that you do (accounts.txt)
2. Also turn on the `error_reporting` if you disabled it, so that you can debug it easily